React How to get all free available plugins and tools for CKEditor, similar to Django
In my Django backend, I have all available CKEditor tools and plugins, but in React, I have very few plugins available. See the two screenshots
django screenshot

react screenshot

Why am I not getting all the tools and plugins like I have in Django in my React app?
my react config:
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
function CreateBlog() {
   
      upload() {
        return this.loader.file.then((file) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('upload', file);
    
            handleAxois(`${domain}/ckeditor/upload/`, 'post', formData, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
            })
              .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data); // Debugging: Check the response to ensure the full URL
                resolve({
                  default: `${domain}${res.data.url}`  // Use the full URL returned from the server
                });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
              });
          })
        );
      }
    
      abort() {}
    }



  return (
    <> <CKEditor
                          editor={ClassicEditor}
                          data={subtitle.description}
                          onChange={(event, editor) => {
                            const data = editor.getData();
                            handleSubtitleChange(index, subtitleIndex, 'description', data);
                          }}
                          config={{
                            extraPlugins: [CustomUploadAdapterPlugin],
                            mediaEmbed: {
                              previewsInData: true
                            },
                            filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckeditor/upload/',
                            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckeditor/upload/',
                            height: 500,
                          }}
                        />
</>
}

